# Initialsing Array of Structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm looking to initialize a global array of stucts in C within the header file however it keeps complaining when compiling. Here's my struct

```
typedef struct
{
 char input[100][100];
 int count;
 char name;
}INPUT;

extern INPUT[] global;
```

Thanks

Comment: "it" keeps "complaining"?  You should tell us what "it" is, and paste the complaint.

Answer (score 1):

In your header, declare an extern pointer to the array e.g.

```
extern INPUT *global;
```

In one of the bodies, declare the actual storage:

```
INPUT global_[N], *global = global_;
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can't initialise it in the header
  file, do it in the C file.
- Use extern if you want to access this
  global array in some other C file.

Answer (score 0):

I had to guess at what you want, I hope this about it:

```
typedef struct {
  char input[100][100];
  int count;
  char name;
} INPUT;

INPUT global[] = {
  { {'x', 'y'}, /* count: */ 1, /* char */ 'x' },
  { {"how now", 'y'}, /* count: */ 1, /* char */ 'x' },
  { {"brown cow", 'y'}, /* count: */ 1, /* char */ 'x' },
  { {"more", " stuff"}, /* count: */ 1, /* char */ 'x' },
  { {{'x', 'y'}, {'a', 'b'}}, /* count: */ 1, /* char */ 'x' },
};
```

Build with `cc -Wall -Wno-missing-braces -c ...`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but can you try by giving the size of the array?
`extern INPUT[100] global;`